# Wordpress website broken in Facebook mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, facebook, browser

i'm facing a weird issue, my website doesn't appear well (without CSS & javascript) only in the Facebook mobile browser.

In Desktop everything is OK, in Mobile with Chrome or other browsers is OK.
But when i open my website link or post link inside facebook in-app browser it appears with no CSS & Javascript.

Screenshot of issue >> https://i.ibb.co/R3R3FLd/222977963-228682545788525-3749803821851752230-n.jpg

notice : I don't have a caching plugin.
i'am using Sucuri CDN, and disabled their cache.

thanks for your help

Comment: Jus had a run at your website (tested on iPhone 8+, Chrome Ios latest), I can't reproduce what you're seeing, every thing renders correctly on my end. Consider updating your browsing app.

Comment: Hello, like i said, you should open the website with Facebook in-app browser...
with Chrome app, the website is OK

Comment: Like I said yesterday. I can confirm that opening it via facebook in-app browser doesn't affect the render. I'm not seeing it on my end.

Comment: Sorry but all my Facebook visitors are facing the issue, i don't know what is the problem.
PS : Not only facebook in-app browser but also Instagram
... Twitter browser works fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a look again, here is the result:

[image]

If multiple users are seeing the same issue, I'm thinking that it's related to your CDN handling, serving an outdated/corrupted version.

You might want to refer to [Troubleshoot Cache Issues](https://docs.sucuri.net/website-firewall/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-cache-issues/).